# Adapt card height to fontSize in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, accessibility, font-size

I have a card with 2 Text widgets and I want to have them not overflowing regardless of the fontSize set in accessibility settings by the user. I'm doing this calculus and it overflows right away.
I added a constant to the total height so it doesn't overflow but when I increased the font size even more from settings it's overflowing again.

What am I missing here?

```
double getCardHeight(BuildContext context) {
final scale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;

double bodyFontSize = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontSize ?? 0;
double bodyLineHeight = bodyFontSize * scale;

double titleFontSize = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.fontSize ?? 0;
double titleLineHeight = titleFontSize * scale;

final textsHeight =
    (titleLineHeight * titleMaxLines) + (bodyLineHeight * bodyMaxLines);
final cardHeight = textsHeight + verticalPadding * 2;
print("card height = $cardHeight");

return cardHeight;}
```

Comment: post the output too

Answer (score 0):

You should do this a bit differently. Instead of calculating the text height and then using that to size the cards, put your text widgets inside Flexible widgets and put those flexible widgets inside a Row.

```
Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text('My text'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
```

This will make it so the text wraps whenever its about to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have my text styles defined in the theme. However, I did not set a height to the styles. When doing the math I assumed the height of the font is 1 but it was not. After I specified height: 1 to all my text styles the math works fine